# Amazon Aurora is slow compare to Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-performance, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have created one instance of Amazon Aurora in Sydney Region and restored my RDS snapshot on it. I am executing one simple query on one of my table which has roughly 6k records in it, returns a very slow result. I have not changed any parameter in default parameter group, which is linked to my instance. This query runs perfectly on my existing RDS instance with same parameters with 0.200sec and returns quick response. But the same query takes about 0.350sec on Aurora. My query plan (EXPLAIN) shows me no issue. It uses PRIMARY Index to get a result. So, I can't understand, Why it is so slow? Do I need to configure parameters? As they claim that Aurora is 5x faster than RDS. How Do I check? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you benchmarked this more thoroughly than a single run of a single query? Note also that they claim (deeper in the docs - the marketing copy is  a bit irresponsible) Aurora is **up to** 5x faster, and **in throughput**, not individual queries.

Comment: How long does `SELECT 1;` take on each machine?  That might gauge how far away they are.  Where are you located (in the world)?

Comment: @RickJames, I am from India and my Instance is located at Sydney, Australia. Does distance matter for this much latency? Currently If I run query on my local mysql database, it returns result in 72 milliseconds, same query from RDS (Singapore) returns result in 172 milliseconds. means approx 100 milliseconds is may be distance latency. Am I right?

Comment: Distance matters due to the latency due to the speed of electrons through the wires.  Opposite sides of the world are at least 200ms apart.  I don't know how straight your links are.  The Australia end of the link may be in the ocean and have to go half way around the country (not straight).  It may even go through Japan to get from India to Sydney.

Comment: @ManishSapkal Hi, I have the same issue to migrate MySQL RDS to Aurora. I suggest you to change the title of question "How to know the difference of interpreting between MySQL and Aurora when EXPLAIN results are the same ?"

Answer (score 3):

Aurora is also a type of Amazon RDS based on MySQL. 
How did you migrate data from RDS (which one?) to Aurora on RDS? Did you use Amazon DMS to migrate data between Mysql/MariaDB/Aurora RDS to Aurora RDS? You said you restored a snapshot - (it's impossible to restore Aurora from non-Aurora snapshot).

I had a performance issue with MariaDB and Aurora when I migrate data from other non RDS MariaDB through Amazon DMS. It was extremely slow! Migration process between MariaDB and RDS DM went without problems, no error/warning logs, but it just work extremely slow, almost all queries took 100 times more time than on standard (much smaller) EC2 instance with MariaDB. I tried to increase IOPS, resizing RDS, changing parameters, etc. Nothing helped!

My solution was to not use DMS migration (which changed a lot in tables creation schemas). I did a `mysqldump` on EC2 Instance with MariaDB and restored it into new MariaDB RDS. Everything started working as expected with a good performance.

Comment: Should we migrate from Aurora to MySQL RDS using DMS without taking downtime or using snapshot. Because my database is very huge (about 16gb) and taking so much time to download using mysqldump. and I don't want to take any downtime

Answer (score 0):

We did not use Amazon DMS to migrate to Amazon Aurora. After considering that among options, instead we used an Aurora Read replica. This piece on database migration to Aurora describes are experience and maybe helpful 
https://blog.codacy.com/database-migration-to-amazon-aurora/